# 301 Redirect old site URL's in new Drupal installation

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-6

I'm looking to 301 redirect an URL from a old version of a site no longer being used to a new URL that has been created in fresh Drupal installation.

Old URL: /198/our-software/

New URL: /services/software-development/

In the .htaccess located in the root directory of Drupal I have added the following:

```
redirect 301 /198/our-software/ http://www.domain.com/services/software-development
```

The redirect is working to some extent, it sends the user to a url like below with a query string appended to the end of it, which results in a 404 error:

http://www.domain.com/services/software-development?q=198/our-software/

I have tried placing the redirect at both the start and end of the .htaccess file both result in a 404 page not found error.

Do I need to use a more complex redirect to get around Drupals URL rewrite?

NOTE: I'm using the Pathauto module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than edit the .htaccess directly, just install the [Path Redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) which has that exact functionality built in.

Note that the Path Redirect module is only available for Drupal 6 (as of 2/22/12)

Comment: The drupal 7 version of this module is available now at https://drupal.org/project/redirect

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with using "RewriteRule" instead, AND (important!) removing the leading slash in the source URL, so in your case:

```
RewriteRule 198/our-software/ http://www.domain.com/services/software-development [R=301,L]
```